# Arquivo .js funciona, componente .jsx não funciona

Tags: javascript, react, componentes, jsx

em um arquivo .js quando vou no meu botão html e chamo a função main, tudo roda belezinha.

Agora se eu transformar em um arquivo .jsx (react) como um componente, quando chamo a função main ele mostra isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function main() {
  dividirQuestoes()
  texto.forEach((element, i) => {
  dividirAlternativas(texto, i)
  }
}
     
function dividirQuestoes() {
  let textoPuro = document.getElementById('cxTexto').value
  texto = textoPuro.split(/ø/i)
  texto.pop()
  return texto
}
```

Oque pode estar acontecendo? Porque o jsx é diferente do JS na execução das funções?
Sou novato em REACT então com certeza é alguma bobeira minha.

Comment: O aviso é que a palavra "texto" não esta definido é apenas um nome solto.. não é foi interpretada com variavel ou lista.

Comment: dentro da função este apenas o nome de outra função chamada "dividirQuestoes()"... e no forEach esta com uma palavra solta que não condiz nada ao código... para o forEach interar a lista ja indique que haveria uma variavel que se chamara texto que tem como ponto de referencia a função  dividirQuestoes... exemplo let var texto = dividirQuestoes(); então o forEach pegara da variavel texto  a referencia da função  dividirQuestoes()

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolvi aqui declarando a variável, oque me intriga, é porque que no arquivo .js ele funciona sem precisar declarar...enfim... mas está resolvido. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Simples amigo já passei por isso algumas vezes quando iniciei , sugiro estudar sobre escopos para que esse problema não venha ocorrer de novo , oque aconteceu foi o seguinte: sua "variavel: texto" não existe oque você acha em declarar ela em um escopo superior? por exemplo

```js
 const texto =  [] //valor do array que você quer fazer o forEach

function main() {
  dividirQuestoes()
  texto.forEach((element, i) => {
  dividirAlternativas(texto, i)
  }
}
     
function dividirQuestoes() {
  let textoPuro = document.getElementById('cxTexto').value
  texto = textoPuro.split(/ø/i)
  texto.pop()
  return texto
}
```

tudo aquilo que está a um escopo superior pode ser vistos pelas demais funções.

Outro problema é que pude notar que você esqueceu de passou as variaveis como argumento mas não para os paramentros perceba :

```js
function main() {
  dividirQuestoes(texto)
  texto.forEach((element, i) => {
  dividirAlternativas(texto, i)
  }
}
 /*aqui nesse parte como você não tem o valor de i a primeira vez que essa função é chamada o ideal seria dar um valor padrão pra ela, caso queira ler mais sobre pesquise por destruturação e defalut value */

function dividirQuestoes(texto , i=0) {
  let textoPuro = document.getElementById('cxTexto').value
  texto = textoPuro.split(/ø/i)
  texto.pop()
  return texto
}
```

assim sua função irá receber tudo aquilo que for tratado no "texto"